# Как можно сделать, чтобы эта страница открывалась именно в модальном окне? (в новом окне получается сделать)

Tags: javascript

```
<td class="djc_image">
<?php if ($item->item_image) { ?>
    <div class="djc_image_in">

        <?php if ((int)$this->params->get('image_link_item') == 1) { ?>

        <?php } else { ?>
            <a href="<?php echo JRoute::_(DJCatalogHelperRoute::getItemRoute($item->slug, (!isset($this->item) || (empty($this->item->catslug))) ? $item->catslug:$this->item->catslug)); ?>"><img class="img-polaroid" alt="<?php echo $item->image_caption; ?>" src="<?php echo DJCatalog2ImageHelper::getImageUrl($item->image_fullpath,'small'); ?>" /></a>
        <?php } ?>
     </div>
<?php } ?>
</td>
```

Есть вот такой код, ссылка которого ведет на детальный просмотр объявления. Как можно сделать, чтобы эта страница открывалась именно в модальном окне? (в новом окне получается сделать).

Comment: что ты подразумеваешь по _модальным_ окном в данном случае? Чем не устраивает новое окно? чем не устраивают модальные попапы, которые не настоящие окна, а просто Html элементы стилизованные нужным образом?

Comment: Модальные окна к великому сожалению как-то не шибко поддерживаются браузерами. Поэтому часто жаваскриптом блочут интерфейс, создают iframe, в который и загружается "модальная" страница.

Comment: вот именно, что не работают модальные попапы, например (fancybox), просто открывается ссылка в том же окне.

Comment: может я не правильно вставляю код попапа или js

Comment: Можете привести пример какой js использовать и куда и какой код нужно вставить.

Comment: _вот именно, что не работают модальные попапы, например (fancybox)_ - как к этому вопросу относится код, приведенный в вопросе? Судя по тому, что просто ссылка открывается - стоит проверить консоль браузера и посмотреть какие ошибки он вывел, ну и самое главное проверить, что нужный плагин подключен

Comment: добавляю перед ссылкой  class="iframe" data-fancybox-type="iframe"

Comment: и использую вот такой скрипт: $(document).ready(function() {
 $(".iframe").fancybox({
  maxWidth : 800,
  maxHeight : 600,
  fitToView : false,
  width  : '70%',
  height  : '70%',
  autoSize : false,
  closeClick : false,
  openEffect : 'none',
  closeEffect : 'none'
 });
});